# How to enforce LSTM to learn monotonic sequences?

Tags: keras, constraints, lstm, forecasting

I'm using LSTM with Keras to forecast a set of sequences. Here my basic model:

```python
inputs = Input(shape=(1,seq_dim))       #seq_dim = 2
# shape = (timesteps, featdim) = (1,2) since my input sequences are pair of values
# I want to predict the sequence of the fist values in the pairs

se = LSTM(lstm_size)(inputs)   

out = Dense(1)(se)   # I want to forecast one value
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)
```

I know for sure that the sequences start from 0 and are monotonic (not-decreasing).
I tried with the Maximum() layer

```python
max_out = Maximum()([output_seq,input_seq])
```

Here the model

```python
inputs = Input(shape=(1,seq_dim))       
# shape = (timesteps, featdim) = (1,2) since my input sequences are pair of values
# I want to predict the sequence of the fist values in the pairs

se = LSTM(lstm_size)(inputs)   

out = Dense(1)(se)   # I want to forecast one value
# max between the output and the previous value of the sequence (current input)
max_out = Maximum()([out,inputs[:,:,0]]) 
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=max_out)
```

however at compiling the model an error is raised:

```python
"AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'"
```

I've also tried with a Lambda layer but it raises the same error.

```python
max_out = Lambda(lambda x: K_BACKEND.max(x))([out,inputs[:,:,0]])
```

How can I add this constrain to my model? Is it possible to do in the architecture definitio (as I'm trying to do), or by editing the loss function?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
`max_out = Lambda( lambda oi: K_BACKEND.maximum( oi[0], oi[1][:,:,0], axis=-1)),output_shape=lambda oi : oi[0] )([out,inputs])`.

Comment: I don't know yet if it works, but with some minor edits the model has been accepted by Keras for training.  In your suggestion there is a bracket  ")" to be removed and the parameter "axis=-1" has to be removed as well. Here is the code:  

max_out = Lambda(lambda oi: K_BACKEND.maximum(oi[0], oi[1][:,:,0]),output_shape=lambda oi : oi[0])([out,inputs])